# TSQL - How do you search a column containing a string using another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to isolate the school ID based on the most recent grade column.  This shows which schools a student is zoned for.  I'm not sure how to search a string based on a column result.  What's the best way to isolate the schoolid?

Thank you.

**Data:**

[image]

**Desired Result:**

[image]

SQL Fiddle code:  (I have trouble getting the schema to build without error.)

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 (
StudentID varchar(10),
AddressID varchar(10),
SchoolID varchar(10),
SchoolGrades varchar(100),
MostRecentGrade varchar(10),
)

INSERT INTO #T1
VALUES
('7777777','297','118','PK,KK,01,02,03,04,05,MG','10'),
('7777777','297','338','06,07,08,MG','10'),
('7777777','297','528','09,10,11,12,MG','10')

SELECT *
FROM #T1
```

Comment: Storing comma-separated data like that in a field is very poor database design that will greatly complicate queries like this.

Comment: Normalize those comma delimited values into a 1-to-many table, your problems with that design are only just beginning ...

Comment: Can you please deisred result as text,images might be blocked in some domains

Comment: Don't store multiple values in a single field as a string of comma separated values.  Just don't.  It's quite a fundamental breach of normalisation which is a fundamental part of relational database design.  Instead, have a separate table that is something like `SchoolID, SchoolGrade` and then put each *individual* grade in a different row.  *(8 rows for School 118, 4 rows for School 338, etc, etc)*

Comment: Granted that storing CSV is an antipattern, you would need a quite awkward query clause such as `WHERE ',' + SchoolGrades + ',' LIKE '%,' + RecentGrade + ',%'`. Note that from your image file, it *looks* like you use **comma plus space** as a separator, not comma alone.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and I don't disagree about the design.  It's not my design, just trying to work with what I have.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have a very poor data structure.  You shouldn't be storing lists in a single column.  You should have a separate table with one row for each grade in each school.  Or, have max and min columns for the grades in a school -- assuming that schools have consecutive grades.

But, you can do what you want using `like`:

```
select t.*
from #t1 t
where ',' + t.schoolgrades + ',' like '%,' + mostrecentgrade + ',%';
```

Comment: With the implied penalty of it not being able to use indexes.

Comment: it might be worth replacing any spaces in SchoolGrades /MostRecentGrade with empty string before comparison